# Angular 12 - getting error 'source.subscribe is not a function'

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 12. I'm trying to create service and I'm getting this error *'source.subscribe is not a function'* in console. How can I solve this? Where am i doing wrong?

**My auth.service is:**

```
  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.token.loggedIn())
  
  authStatus = this.loggedIn.asObservable


  changeAuthStatus(value: boolean){
    this.loggedIn.next(value)
  }
```

**My component is:**

```
 public loggedIn: any;

  constructor(
    private Auth: AuthService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.Auth.authStatus().subscribe((value) => {
      this.loggedIn = value
    });

  }
```

Comment: `authStatus = this.loggedIn.asObservable()`? Did you forget the parenthesis after `asObservable`?

Comment: my faults are incredible... i make such a mistake today for the second time.. now its working thank you